# How to reformat the substring starting with Seat N: pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

How to replace the string that maches following pattern format

```
Seat x: SomeUsername collected ($1234.56)
```

to

```
Seat x: SomeUsername did not showed and won $1234.56
```

without replacing other strings? The username can contain spaces.

Example:

```
...
PridvorD collected $582.00 from pot
PridvorD: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $585.00 | Rake $3.00 
Board [5c Qc 2c 8d]
Seat 1: Walleater folded on the Flop
Seat 3: PridvorD collected ($582.00) # The only string that matches replacement pattern
Seat 4: KingsPower folded on the Flop
...
```

Desired output:

```
...
PridvorD collected $582.00 from pot
PridvorD: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $585.00 | Rake $3.00 
Board [5c Qc 2c 8d]
Seat 1: Walleater folded on the Flop
Seat 3: PridvorD did not showed and won $582.00
Seat 4: KingsPower folded on the Flop
...
```

Comment: PLease show what ytou tried. It seems like a very simple use of `re.sub()`.

Comment: You need 3 capture groups: One for the seat number, one for the username, and one for the amount they collected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an easy case for re.sub.

```
import re

def reformat_string(s):
    pattern = r'(Seat \d+:) (.*?)( collected \(\$([\d\.]+)\))'
    replacement = r'\1 \2 did not show and won $\4'
    return re.sub(pattern, replacement, s)

# Sample input
input_string = """
PridvorD collected $582.00 from pot
PridvorD: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $585.00 | Rake $3.00 
Board [5c Qc 2c 8d]
Seat 1: Walleater folded on the Flop
Seat 3: PridvorD collected ($582.00) 
Seat 4: KingsPower folded on the Flop
"""

# Get the reformatted output
output_string = reformat_string(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

Please add more detail if this is insufficient.